# The action 'update' could not be found for Api::UsersController:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am sending an AJAX request from my frontend to rails for a patch request but getting an action cannot be found error.

So far, I have double checked my routes and controller to make sure there were no mistakes. My create action is working fine which is in the users controller. Ive also double checked my AJAX request to make sure it is going to the correct url. My AJAX request is also for an AWS upload if that helps.

### Here are my routes

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
 resources :users, only: [:create, :update, :show]
    resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy, :show]

  end 
  root "static_pages#root"
end
```

### here is my controller with the update action

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController
    def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      login(@user)
      render "api/users/show"
    else
      render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: 422
    end

    def show 
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      render "api/users/show"
    end

    def update 
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          render "api/users/show"
        else 
          render json: @user.errors.full_messages
        end 
    end 

  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name, :DOB, :gender, :prof_photo, :cover_photo)
  end
end
```

Update: ajax request for AWS user photo upload.

```
export const updateUser = (userId, formData) => {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "PATCH",
        url: `api/users/${userId}`,
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
}
```

### Finally here are the server logs

`````
AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'update' could not be found for Api::UsersController:

Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2019-10-06 07:49:03 -0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#root as HTML
  Rendering static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."session_token" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["session_token", "mRbshUiTIXjVd3LpZSiWvA"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:10
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2], ["record_type", "User"], ["name", "prof_photo"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/api/users/_user.json.jbuilder:3
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/api/users/_user.json.jbuilder:3
  Rendered api/users/_user.json.jbuilder (7.2ms)
  Rendered static_pages/root.html.erb within layouts/application (13.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 93ms (Views: 86.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)


Started PATCH "/api/users/2" for ::1 at 2019-10-06 07:55:37 -0400

AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'update' could not be found for Api::UsersController:````
`````

Comment: How many users controllers do you have? Can you double check in your app/controllers/api/users_controller.rb whether the relevant update action is there?

Comment: sorry if theres any confusion i only posted a snippet of the controller. to clarify I only have one users controller. The above code comes from the users controller in api/user_controller. In response to tan's question, contentType is set to false currently since im trying to format for AWS. However, i did try to set it to json but it did not work as well. Ive updated the code above to include the full AJAx requestion.

Comment: Is your file named "user_controller" or "users_controller"? it should be plural but you wrote it in singular. Is the action public? maybe you have it below the protected or private statements. Show your controller

Comment: Have you referenced properly the namespace in the controller first line?

Comment: the file is named users_controller, its not under private. updated controller to full controller

Answer (score 0):

Found the rookie mistake! The end statement for create action was all the way at the bottom (hence only my create action was working) Make sure to check your end statements!